# how to mask 2d array by if there are at least 2 neighbors greater than one value?

Tags: python, numpy

For a 2d numpy array, e.g.,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5, 4)
a
```

`a` looks like

```
array([[0.92576936, 0.41860519, 0.26446948, 0.31691141],
       [0.31797497, 0.2044637 , 0.20939504, 0.54034017],
       [0.85781227, 0.40367301, 0.40215265, 0.95902499],
       [0.15700837, 0.10680368, 0.61971475, 0.35586694],
       [0.25211967, 0.98171005, 0.60740472, 0.89452886]])
```

Apparently, each element has neighbors. For elements in the border, it has 3 or 5 neighbors. And for central elements, it has 8. Thus, is there an efficient and elegant way to mask `a` by only selecting elements and their neighbors **together** greater than 0.5? That means, do not consider **isolated** elements larger than 0.5, whose neighbors all smaller than 0.5.

For `a`, the expected output mask would be

```
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False , False, True],
       [False, False, False, True],
       [False, False, True, False],
       [False, True, True, True]])
```

Comment: Please provide expected output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you provide a clear example (use `np.random.seed(0)` and the exact expected output)

Comment: I have added the expected output now. So far, I can only derive this mask by loop over elements of `np.where(a > 0.5)`, and exclude the elements without any neighbors > 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 2D convolution:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

kernel = np.array([[1, 1,  1],
                   [1, 10, 1],
                   [1, 1,  1]])

out = convolve2d(a>0.5, kernel, mode='same') > 10
```

The kernel is designed to count 10 for each center > 0.5 and 1 for each surrounding value > 0.5, and the convolution computes the sum. Thus if you have a total sum > 10, you know that the value is > 0.5 and so it at least one of its neighbors.

Output:

```
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

#### more classical alternative

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

m = a>0.5

kernel = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1]])

out = m & (convolve2d(m, kernel, mode='same') > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works perfectly by using 2d convolution.